# Any way to implement Token base (JWT) authentication in basic license of Elasticsearch

Tags: rest, authentication, elasticsearch, jwt, elasticsearch-api

We are using basic license of Elasticsearch 8.7.1 and want to implement JWT authentication, but when we add Realm for JWT authentication using `token type = access-token` getting following warning in log file:

```
[WARN ][o.e.x.s.a.RealmsAuthenticator] [ASALEEM] No authentication credential 
could be extracted using realms 
[reserved/reserved,file/default_file,native/default_native].
```

- `Realms [jwt/jwt2]` were skipped because they are not permitted on the current license.
- Is there workaround or (using 3rd part or any plugin install process) to make jwt authentication work for basic license?